# what's the url of oauth sso in wso2is?

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I'm working with oauth for sso authentication using wso2 identity server but i don't found the url of sso like https://localhost:9443/samlsso in saml ?
can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the endpoints related to oauth2 in wso2 identity  server.

- Authorization Endpoint : https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize
- Token Endpoint         : https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
- Revoke Endpoint        : https://localhost:9443/oauth2/revoke

Additionally

- Openid Connect Userinfo Endpoint : https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo

Here assumption is the identity server is running locally and has port offset set zero